# How to congratulate a professor for a grant achievements?

Tags: graduate-school, email, communication

I recently got the news that my prof and his colleagues were got many grants/funding.
Is it common to write them a congratulation?

I prepared this simple sentences, how should I wish him more success in the future for his ever growing research group?

> Congratulations on your recent achievements.

Comment: You might also consider adding something to the effect of “I look forward to seeing the outcomes of this fascinating research proposal!”

Comment: A caveat: at least in the research culture I work in, *many* grants is a double-edged sword, and congratulating someone for winning them all might be perceived as sarcasm. Not inherently bad, but also not necessarily what you wanted and definitely best done in-person rather than "I've heard some rumors that..."

Answer (score 5):

If you feel like congratulating your professor, go ahead and do it. He might appreciate it, or in the worst case he will ignore because he has too many emails in his inbox. But I cannot imagine a scenario where the professor would take such a congratulation email negatively.

As with most emails to busy people: keep the email short and to the point. Just one sentence like the one you wrote, though maybe using a more specific term than "your recent achievements":

> Congratulations on receiving Grant X[!]

where the use of the exclamation mark [!] depends on where you are and what you have seen your colleagues do in emails (and also on whether you want to use it of course).

Answer (score 2):

It depends a lot on your relation with your prof. I'd say something like "I spotted you got the xxx grant - congratulations!" when meeting them on the floor, or add something similar at the end of an email that you would have sent anyway (planning the next meeting, asking for feedback, etc) - don't overthink it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a situation where you are likely to meet face to face then a spoken word is also an option. In fact, a colleague would be most likely to offer congratulations in an elevator ride or if they meet informally in a coffee lounge. The latter can lead to a longer conversation about how you are doing and your plans.

For a student, if you meet in their office for another reason, you can add something at the end of the meeting like "Oh by the way,..."

Pre-COVID this used to be pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

Stay out of it - it's not your business, even if there may be something in it for your research group: he will announce it in his own time to you all.

How do you know this anyhow ?

Propogating rumours is not something you want to get a name for.

Neither do you want to be the type who wants success by association.

Comment: This seems an odd answer. I don't understand the reasoning.

Comment: @Buffy I am assuming this OP is a student of the grant obtaining professor, i.e. an undergrad or postgrad of that Department. I don't see what value a student's "congratulations" would have to this professor. After all, the professor prepared the research bid, drafted it up and justified it in person in a tough one-against-several meeting all after years of struggle in that field of research. But sadly - based on experience of postgrads (even certain undergrads) - I can see how offering congratulations might be of use to an academically ambitious student. And I object to unmerited promotion.